# MQ - How to get Trigger Type(TrigType) com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue in Java

Tags: ibm-mq

We have existing application in JAVA  which uses com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue  to send MQ messages to IBM Mainframe CICS application.

How to get the Triggertype in Java?

The MQSeries MQ  Trigger type is set to "NONE" for Batch processing during night for 30 mins. We want to check the triggertype in Java Application and display appropriate error message to user.

Please let me know how to get the Trigger type in JAVA.
MQQueue - getTriggerType method is available for com.ibm.mq.MQQueue and not available for com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Please let me know how to get the Trigger type in JAVA. MQQueue -
>   getTriggerType method is available for com.ibm.mq.MQQueue and not
>   available for com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue

True.  The JMS specification does not support the method because it is an IBM MQ only method.  You need to use the MQ classes for Java (and not JMS).